# Bootstrap 3 Glyphicons not displayed in Grails GSP Page

Tags: css, grails, fonts, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I have a grails application and I integrated Bootstrap 3.
Everything is working fine except the glyphicons are not displayed/shown in my page.

I have the following code in my login page.

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon ">
        <i class="icon-user icon-color"></i>
    </span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="Username" required="required" />
</div>
```

and what is displayed in my page is:[image: textbox with no glyphicon]

[The orange circle indicates where the glyphicon should have appeared/displayed]

CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.2.1') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'),    url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

**My folder structure**

[image: folder]

I added /fonts/* in **Config.groovy** like

```
// What URL patterns should be processed by the resources plugin
grails.resources.adhoc.patterns = ['/images/*', '/css/*', '/js/*', '/plugins/*', '/fonts/*']
```

**Error shown in Google Chrome (F12)**
[image: error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spring-security's rule may not be configured on Config.groovy :), see:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
  (...)
  '/**/fonts/**':                 ['permitAll'],
  (...)
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I found the solution!

I added the following line to Config.groovy and the Glyphicons are not being displayed.

```
grails.resources.adhoc.includes = ['/images/**', '/css/**', '/js/**', '/plugins/**', '/fonts/**']
```

I had already added /fonts/* in Config.groovy like

// What URL patterns should be processed by the resources plugin

```
grails.resources.adhoc.patterns = ['/images/*', '/css/*', '/js/*', '/plugins/*', '/fonts/*']
```

but now, grails.resources.adhoc.**includes** is added.

Answer (score 1):

you can take https://github.com/glancekit/glance as an example.
It works with grails 2.3.8 and Bootstrap 3. All Glyphicons are displayed correctly in glance.

-markus

Comment: Thanks. Not just for the glyphicons but the app is very nice too. Great work!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your syntax might be wrong.

I'm not sure about the `user-color` icon but for `user-icon` I believe the classes should be:

```
<i class="fa fa-user"></i>
```

This assumes you're using the latest version of Font Awesome. If you're using Foundations Icon Fonts 3, the class name should start with an `fi-` prefix. And for BS3 it should be:

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i>
```

Comment: It is not just a syntax issue. Please look at the error in chrome I posted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It should be using span:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

reference: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-how-to-use